# Postgres RDS: is there a way to use LDAP authentication?

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora, ldap

We have a client interested in using LDAP (specifically Active Directory) for user authentication on a PostgreSQL AWS RDS (Aurora, specifically) database.

Anybody doing this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

As much I am aware this may not be possible. 
Currently, AWS has IAM authentication for postgres which in my humble opinion has a bit further to go before it can be adopted. ie once the IAM user is mapped to the DB Role any once can create a token on behalf on a DB role.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried it out personally, since the time this question was asked AD & Kerberos support were added to Postgres RDS: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-supports-user-authentication-with-kerberos-and-microsoft-active-directory/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/176449)